# If statement not doing what I want it to

Tags: java

My if statement isn't working when I try to get the direction of a vector in my program.

The problem is when I input a vector of <-1, 1>

I get 45° instead of 125°

Source code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Decloration
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rty;
        double v1;
        double v2;
        double dir;
        double mag;
        double V1;
        double V2;

        do {
        //Input
                System.out.println("Please input x");
        v1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please input y");
        v2 = in.nextDouble();

        //Calculating
        dir = Math.toDegrees( Math.atan(v2/v1) );
        if (v1 >= 0) {
            if (v2 < 0) {
                dir+=270;
            }
        } else {
            if (v2 < 0) {
                dir+=180;
            } else {
                dir+=90;
            }
        }
        mag = Math.sqrt((v1*v1)+(v2*v2));
        V1 = v1/mag;
        V2 = v2/mag;

        //Output
        System.out.println("The unit vector is <" + V1 +", " + V2 + ">");
        System.out.println("The magnitude is " + mag);
        System.out.println("The direction is " + dir);
        System.out.println("\n\nRty?");

        //Quit
        rty = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n");
        dir = 0;
        } while (rty == 1);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: To start with, you probably want `Math.atan2(v2, v1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect for all cases where at least one of `v1` and `v2` is negative.  The [`atan` method Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan-double-) state that:

> the returned angle is in the range -pi/2 through pi/2

So if a value `v1` is `0` or positive and `v2` is negative, you'll wind up with `-45` and you should add `360` degrees so that an input of (1, -1) is 325 degrees.

If a value `v1` is negative and `v2` is positive, you'll wind up with the same value as the above case, but you want the opposite direction.  Add 180 degrees here.

If both `v1` and `v2` are negative, the degrees value you'll get is `45`, so adding `180` here is correct.

Here is the updated logic:

```
if (v1 >= 0) {
    if (v2 < 0) {
        dir += 360;
    }
} else {
    dir += 180;
}
```

This will get you the correct value of `135` degrees, not `125`, for (-1, 1).

However, getting the range of degrees (or originally radians) across the entire range of -pi to +pi is the job of [`Math.atan2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-).  It takes polar coordinates, which is what `v1` and `v2` are.

> ... computing an arc tangent of y/x in the range of -pi to pi.

```
dir = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(v2, v1));
```

After converting to degrees, you will still want to add `360` degrees if the `dir` is negative.  The logic is simpler:

```
if (dir < 0) {
    dir += 360;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs, [`atan(double a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan%28double%29)

> Returns the arc tangent of a value; the returned angle is in the range -pi/2 through pi/2.

From docs, [`atan2(double a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29)

> Returns the angle theta from the conversion of rectangular coordinates (x, y) to polar coordinates (r, theta). This method computes the phase theta by computing an arc tangent of y/x in the range of -pi to pi.

The use of `atan` was scaling your answer down by `pi` to get it into the range of the values returned by the function. Switching to `atan2` would solve that since the cartesian coordinates are converted to polar coordinates. You can obviously then use the `toDegrees` function.

Comment: Might want to check if the returned degrees is negative. If it is, scale up by 360. I think it would be best if you tackle that problem yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.toDegrees( Math.atan(v2/v1)` returns -45 and then you're adding 90, so it will give 45.

For your if clauses this should work:

```
Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.abs(v2/v1))
```